# PouchDB pouchdb-find problems with sort

Tags: pouchdb

I'm trying to find some data by the selector with special type and then sort these data by name in a promise:

```
 this._DB.createIndex({
  index: { fields: ['typ', 'name'] },
  ddoc: "my-index-design-doc"
}) 

     return new Promise(resolve => {
      this._DB.find({
        selector: { typ: 'klasse', name: {$ne:1} },
        fields: ['typ', 'name'],
        sort: [ {'name': 'desc'} ],
        use_index: 'my-index-design-doc',
      }).then(function (result) {
        //console.log("Klassen: "+ JSON.stringify(result));
        resolve(result.docs);
      });
    });
```

I  read https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html , but there is no example for different sorting than the selector is. Here  https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find  are some more detailed examples.

The code itself should work now, but I've still two problems:

1: The index is not ready from the beginning, but when I add a `.then( ...`  the promise doesn't work anymore.

2: Sorting by 'typ' works, but when I use 'name' it's not working.

Comment: Could you add a catch block so the error from the Promise is logged? That would help understand the error. Without a "then" after createIndex it is possible the index is created after the "find" is executed - I am not sure from the code you have posted.

Comment: I tried several of catch block positions, but there was no other output than this simpel error. When adding a .then I'm getting other errors. I found so far no way to get this working.

Comment: From what I read https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7207 , one can only sort on the first field listed in your index creation fields.

Comment: `... Sorting by 'typ' works, but when I use 'name' it's not working ...` That's how *array keys* or *compound keys* work in CouchDB/PouchDB. Take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647616/3405291).